# vue.js use background image in scoped style

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js. I want to use a an image as body background in two components but I don't want other components have this background image. So I tried this:

```
<style scoped>

html,
body {
    background: url(../assets/background.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

</style>
```

But it doesn't work. then when I remove `scoped` from `style` tag it works and effects all templates. why is that ?

Comment: why is that? because [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more beneficial to know the html and css basics before starting to use JS Frameworks.

Style scoped is used to make the style only apply to the html tags that are in that vue component.

Body is html tag that is parent to all html elements user sees in a web page.

You are basically over writing whole webpage background when you remove scoped.

Please write your css to target element in your component e.g. Inside template element create a div element with class "background-img" and style that class in component css.